# Create collection from multiple sources where relationship is 1:n and maintain delegation

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I have a project owners list in SharePoint. There can be more than one project owner for a given project (1:n).

In my app, I want to create some collections OnStart to keep the UI quick and responsive. I have created a collection that contains a distinct list of the projects that the current user is the owner of:

```
ClearCollect(
    MyProjects,
    Filter(
        Project_Owners, //SP list, contains the project ID along with the owner id
        Owner_ID = _myProfile.UserPrincipalName
        )
);
```

This works well and should continue to work even as the SP list exceeds 500 records. But next I want to create a collection that contains *all* the owners for the projects the current user is the owner of. I can achieve this like so:

```
ClearCollect(
    MyProjectOwners,
    Filter(
        Project_Owners, //SP list, contains the project ID along with the owner id
        Project_ID in MyProjects.Project_ID
    )
);
```

The problem here though is that `in` is not delegable with SharePoint, so I'm concerned that once the project owners list exceeds 500 rows my app won't show the correct data.

I cannot find a good reference anywhere that discusses how to do a 1:n lookup like this without sacrificing delegation.

Am I missing something obvious here? How can I maintain delegation in this situation?

Comment: I remember faced similar issue using in operator, can I suggest slightly different way if it works for you. How about you add another screen called details. For ex Project owner 1 has 5 Projects. Now click on Project1 and there you show all the project owners for this Project? will that work for you.

Comment: @AnkUser No, the collection will drive report-like functionality on the main screen and I cannot offload that functionality to another screen for UX reasons.